# Haskell instance read for newtype that is just an int

Tags: haskell, newtype, deriving

I am new to Haskell and I want to be able to a newtype so I can tell what is what, but I also have to read it from a string. I have

```
newtype SpecialId Int
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

I want to be able to `read "5" :: SpecialId` if I derive Read in the newtype it doesn't work it only works on `read "SpecialId 5" :: SpecialId`. I have tried

```
instance Read SpecialId where
    readsPrec _ s = read s
```

But this gives me

```
SpecialId *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Comment: You are Asking Haskell that `read`, reads an `[(SpecialId,String)]`, and this fails, since it does not begin with a `'['` char.

Comment: Your syntax for defining the new type is wrong; it should be `newtype SpecialId = SpecialId Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible since GHC 8.2 using [`-XDerivingStrategies`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-strategies):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}

newtype SpecialId = SpecialId Int
    deriving stock   (Eq, Ord, Show)
    deriving newtype Read
```

In ghci:

```
ghci> read "5" :: SpecialId 
SpecialId 5
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a language extension if you're willing to forward to the `Int` instance manually:

```
instance Read SpecialId where
    readsPrec n s = [ (SpecialId x, y) | (x, y) <- readsPrec n s ]
```

Despite appearances this is not a recursive use of `readsPrec`: We call the `Int` version of `readsPrec` to get a list of `(Int, String)` pairs, then we use a list comprehension to wrap every `Int` in a `SpecialId`.